# Disable anonymous user in Sitecore

Tags: c#, authentication, sitecore, single-sign-on

I'm using an 3rd party external authentication/Single-Sign-On server with Sitecore that returns tickets back to a web server.

The integration documentation recommends that when you get the authorised response back from the server you create your own `FormsAuthenticationTicket`, then you can access user `UserData` entered in the ticket like this:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ((FormsIdentity)   HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket;

if (ticket != null)
{
  string UserData = ticket.UserData;
  ...
}
```

The issue I have is that the User.Identity will always be the `extranet\Anonymous User`.

Is there any way to stop the anonymous user from being used as the current user. Or will I have to create my own membership provider in order for this to work?

Comment: You won't need another membership provider, but probably you will need to do a new login in your code on the callback of your authentication provider. What is actually contained in that ticket?

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll give it a try. The ticket contains user information - like address details etc. and for compliance need to be encrypted.

Comment: I guess you could create a Sitecore user based on the callback data or otherwise use a generic user for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to avoid creating a custom membership provider by using the `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager` to build a virtual user and assign that user to a *real* role in Sitecore. This way you can restrict access for unauthenticated users (by denying read access to the `extranet\anonymous` user account and enabling read access for your custom extranet role. The code (after validating username/password) would be something like this:

```
using Sitecore.Security.Authentication;

var user = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("someone", isAuthenticated: true);
user.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add("extranet\\some role");
AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(user);
```

Comment: +1 for virtual users, defo the way to go and no head ache of maintaining a fake user list

Comment: Thanks, guys. This looks like the way to go and would definitely meet requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar using the WIF module. When I received the ticket back from the system, I extracted the data about the user from the ticket. I then created/updated a Sitecore user for that account (I could have used virtual users, but in this case I wanted the accounts to be true Sitecore accounts).

The final step was to call the Login explicitly to ensure the current context user is the newly created user.